# JetBrains - equal to Eclipse quick doc

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

There is Hover in Eclipse, which enable a quick doc when cursor flies through a word. I already know I can enable "show quick doc on mouse move" in Jetbrains to get that feature.

But, in Eclipse, I can also press F2 to focus (popup a small window puffed with quick doc), even though the cursor's somewhere else. With plugin like Vrapper and IdeaVim, most of time I can free both my hands to get them dirty with keyboard, so 'F2 focus' means a lot to me in Eclipse. I miss this feature while I'm using Jetbrains(AS), how to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

Accidentally, I found the default shortcut Ctrl+Q (Quick Documentation) will meet. As I'm using Vim like plugin IdeaVim, Ctrl+Q here means block mode. But it's not a big deal, I just have to bind another key for this.